# Weird thing going on with domain. if Entered without www.domain.com, goes to wrong host

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, host, nameservers

Hey all I got a quick question for you that are more experienced than me with hosting etc :)
I made a website and firs put it on one host and entered it's nameservers on my purchased domain website to link them of course. After that, I figured that host is too slow, so I changed to other host, and after that also changed my nameservers to be the ones of the new host. Now I have a problem, If someone goes to http://zipdaturl.com he gets redirected to the default index.php page of the old host and if it is with http://www.zipdaturl.com it goes to the correct one. 
What is it that I can do so that both of these go to the correct host ? I checked domain provider,  both nameservers are pointing to the new correct host.

Comment: How long this is happening?

Comment: Since I changed the host.

Comment: Yeah, but how many days sry? It could be that world wide DNSes need some restart since domain transfer take some days to complete. I would be patient about this matter for ie 5 days.

Comment: Ah cool, didnt know that one :) I thought that as soon as a nameserver is successfuly detected by the host for a domain it switches it :) I will wait then. I dealth with nameservers yesterday.

Comment: Yeah, www DNS caches are (probably & still) registering latest host provider static IP for your website so this is "normal www behaviour" for a few days when you are changing hosts. Domain transfer is hugest www change and you always need few days for that to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, www DNS caches are (I'm sure) registering latest host provider static IP for your website so this is "normal www behaviour" for a few days when you are changing hosts. Domain transfer is hugest www change (for one domain/website) and you always need few days for that to complete.

In that period you have 2 (here and there) "hosts".

Funny, depending on a location youre visiting your site, you can see actual site, or you can see old one - at the same time.

But old one will vanish in few days. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Contact your old nameserver provider and tell him to remove the domain from his parkings OR create an index.html on your old host like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.zipdaturl.com/">
```

Comment: Hm, don't want forwarding to the real website, but did create a ticket for them to remove my domain from their parkings, hoping they will do it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have checked and both `URL` took me to the same `website`.but I think you also need to do `WWW` redirection using `ht access`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __controller.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zipdaturl\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.zipdaturl.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Mostly domains need some time to be point in. You can check it by pinging(`window+r` type `cmd`).

```
ping -t www.zipdaturl.com
```

and check the upcoming response `IP Address`

Comment: Tried adding
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __controller.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zipdaturl\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.zipdaturl/$1 [L,R=301]

To the .htaccess but it does nothing

Comment: Still not working, though I am guessing it is because of the thing Xfile mentioned up there in a comment. WW DNS didnt update it still, so that is probably a problem. I'll update here in a few days if the problem still exists

Comment: Yeap, same IP for both www.zipdaturl.com and zipdaturl.com so it must the the same host :)